# How can loop continue before method is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener, runnable

I have multiple threads(runnables) in my program. On of theme is handling RS232 communication.
My problem is that code inside the loop is not executed in the order that is written:

```
while(!serialData.dataToSend.isEmpty())
{
    try {
        SerialMsgToSend msgObject = serialData.dataToSend.remove();
        if(msgObject.type == msgObject.HOLDING_REGISTER)
        {
            Thread.sleep(COMMAND_WAIT_TIME);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            modBusManager.singleRegisterWriteToMultipleRegisters(msgObject.unit, msgObject.startRegisterAdress, msgObject.data);
        }
        else if(msgObject.type == msgObject.COIL)
        {
            Thread.sleep(COMMAND_WAIT_TIME);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
            modBusManager.writeToCoil(msgObject.unit, msgObject.startRegisterAdress, msgObject.data[0] == 1);
        }
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        readUnitsData(msgObject.unit);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        if(msgObject.RESPONSE > 0)
        {
            serialData.listeners[msgObject.unit - 1].sendResponseToServer(msgObject.RESPONSE);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception on sending data: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

First I write to ModBus register with calling:

```
modBusManager.singleRegisterWriteToMultipleRegisters(msgObject.unit, msgObject.startRegisterAdress, msgObject.data);
```

After that I want to wait 5 seconds that registers are updated, then read them and send information to server.

I read the data with calling method:

```
readUnitsData(msgObject.unit);
```

And then I am using listener to tell another thread to send data to server:

```
serialData.listeners[msgObject.unit - 1].sendResponseToServer(msgObject.RESPONSE);
```

My problem is that data is sent to server before it gets read/updated so I send old data. I am used that code is executed in the order that is written. Am I using threads in a wrong way or what could be the problem?

Here is method which I call to read data:

```
private void readUnitsData(int unitID) 
{
    if(mtxData.climatList[unitID] != null)
    {
        try 
        {
            log.info("Serial reading data for: " + unitID);
            int[] coils = modBusManager.readCoils(unitID + 1,0,87);
            String[] holding = modBusManager.readHoldingRegisters(unitID + 1,0,64); //(int slaveAdress, int registerAdress, int registerQuntaity)
            if(coils != null && holding != null)
            {
                System.out.println("send to listner: "  + unitID);
                serialData.listeners[unitID].newHoldingAndCoilData(holding, coils);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            log.error("Exception on run: " + ex.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

And method inside other runnable, which is connected to listener:

```
@Override
public void sendResponseToServer(int responseType) 
{
    try
    {
        log.info("listener for sendStatusToServer called: " + responseType);
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        switch(responseType)
        {
            case 1:
                communicationManager.sendStatus();
                break;
            case 2:
                communicationManager.sendSettings();
                break;
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.error("Exception on sendResponseToServer: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code posted I see no reason why it should not be executed in the written order. Except for the occurence of an `Exception`.  Are you sure, that none of your other threads is tempering with your communication-objects?

Comment: @MarkusMitterauer I have only one thread which starts communication writing/reading to ModBus. To me it looks like that thread which handles RS232, always waits for listener to finish before readUnitsData() is called. Because I added the increased Thread.sleep(15000) to bigger number and with that it time to readUnitsData() also increased. Is OK to use runnables and listeners in a way that I use them, or what could be the problem?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid, I don't know other advice than to try [to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program and see what really happens. -- As I said, I see no problem in the code you provided, but multi-threading is a difficult topic and there might be still traps in the code you run in your other threads. Take it appart. Run only this one thread. (remote) debug it and/or add more log-statements. Understand what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did like @Markus Mitterauer proposed and took apart the code. I found that that it was problem with one of the unitID's which was wrong. Because of that I didn't get any values when reading registers and listener wasn't triggered correctly.

Comment: Great. Then just tick this as *the answer* to your question.